# stopPropagation on input field inside a Link component

Tags: reactjs

I´m using a react router Link component and an input field inside it. how should I stop propagation?

```
<Link to="my-page">
    <input onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()} />
</Link>
```

Tried with onFocus, onClick but the Link is still triggered

Comment: what is the useCase here? why have you put input field inside the Link tag? Just to understand it a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  <div
    onClick={() => {
      console.log("propagated");
      navigate("/my-page");
    }}
  >
    <input type="text" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} />
  </div>;
```